# Externalize java wrapper

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, wrapper

I developed an application spring-boot. For making REST requests I created many mapper like this snippet

```
....
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class IssueFieldsWrapper {

    @JsonProperty("description")
    private String description;

    @JsonProperty("customfield_10406")
    private String mobileNumber;

....
}
```

The problem is that the production environment doesn't  have the same JsonProperties(customfield_10406). For example mobileNumber in Prod has the property "customfield_10500" and I should declared it like that

```
@JsonProperty("customfield_10500")
private String mobileNumber;
```

Would you have any propositions ?

Best regards

Comment: You could store the literals into properties files that are environment specific and fetch them from there (via an autowired Environment object)

Comment: Thanks @Sorin I dont how I can process. Could you have an example ?

Comment: say if you run in production any two separate time will this 'customfield_10406' remain same?

Comment: say if you run in production any two separate time will this 'customfield_10406' remain same?

Comment: Yes it's same attribute but when I make a request in Prod I get a JSON with an attribut "customfield_10500" but in developpment environement I get it with id "customfield_10406" .